# How can I upload file in Apollo server V4

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, apollo-server, cloudinary

I’m using the newer version of apollo server V4, I need assistance on how to upload images or videos from Frontend to  cloudinary and save the url to MongoDB database… please help

I have read through Apollo docs but there are no answers there… I’m kind of stuck now

Comment: did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 7):

There's a great [blog post by Apollo on Apollo file uploads here](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/file-uploads/file-upload-best-practices/), essentially they recommend using a 3rd party image service or pre-signed upload urls (e.g. fetch a pre-signed url via graphql, upload the image directly to that url, then save the location / id of the image through a graphql mutation).

There is a standard for uploading images through a graphql request, although Apollo don't recommend it, but the most popular Node.js package to help with this is [graphql-upload](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload).

To get this working with Apollo 4 and Express (if this is what you're using), you'll need to follow their instructions for [using express middleware here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/express-middleware/#example).

Note that Apollo will block "simple" CORS requests to prevent CSRF attacks, which is likely to affect your image upload, so you need to follow the [instructions here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/cors/#graphql-upload) to include additional headers in your request or disable CSRF protection (not recommended). You can see an example of this by excluding the `Apollo-Require-Preflight` header from the CURL request below.

Here's a [minimal example of graphql upload in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/apollo4-graphql-upload-express-2nnbw4?file=%2Findex.mjs).

And a CURL request to test it

```
$ curl https://2nnbw4-4000.csb.app/ \
  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation ($id: String!, $image: Upload!) { uploadImage(id: $id, image: $image) { id filename } }", "variables": { "image": null, "id": "1" } }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.image"] }' \
  -F 0=@tmp.jpg \
  -H 'Apollo-Require-Preflight: true'

{"data":{"uploadImage":{"id":"1","filename":"tmp.jpg"}}}
```

Comment: Sharing @phdesign's blog post about how he came up with this solution, too. Thanks! https://phdesign.com.au/programming/apollo-server-4-serverless-graphql-upload/

Answer (score 0):

In the response section of the Upload request to Cloudinary, you will receive the URL in the key: `url`.

Sample response: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_response

You would be able to save this to your database through GraphQL. I'm not sure where you're stuck ( is the Apollo server connected to the DB? ) but I would advise looking up some guides on how to store data utilizing Apollo/GraphQL.

https://www.apollographql.com/tutorials/fullstack-quickstart/connecting-to-data-sources
https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/intro-graphql/graphql-mutations/

Comment: Thank you for your response, another problem I’m having is I can’t add Upload scalar  to the newer Apollo/server v4 GraphQL schema… so there is no way to to upload the file for mutation

Comment: Maybe I don’t ask the right question. I’m unable to create a schema for upload on the newer Apollo server version

Comment: In the original question it sounds like you're using Cloudinary as an image upload service, so usually you would 1. Upload your image to Cloudinary and receive an id / location in the response, then 2. Make GraphQL request to your server to save the id / location. In your comment above you're asking about uploading files in GraphQL so I've added another answer on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs this:
A simple workaround for image upload is to convert the image to base64 string at the frontend and send it like any other string. At the backend, you can then save it back as an image.